# Want a active excel sheet names in python?

Tags: python, excel

I have loaded a excel into python (Google Colab), but I was wondering if there was a way of extracting the names of the excel (.xlsm) file. Please check attached image.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['202009 Testing - September - Diamond Plod Day & Night MKY021.xlsm']),sheet_name='1 D',header=8,usecols='BE,BH',nrows=4)
df1 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['202009 Testing - September - Diamond Plod Day & Night MKY021.xlsm']),sheet_name='1 D',header=3)

df=df.assign(PlodDate='D5')
df['PlodDate']=df1.iloc[0,3]
df=df.assign(PlodShift='D6')
df['PlodShift']=df1.iloc[1,3]
df =df.rename({'Qty.2':'Loads','Total (L)':'Litres'},axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=['PlodDate','PlodShift','Loads','Litres','DataSource'])
df=df.assign(DataSource='Name of the Source File')
df
```

Instead of the `datasource='name of the source file'`, I want active excel sheet name.

Output should be:
`Datasource='202009 Testing - September - Diamond Plod Day & Night MKY021'`

As I have a file for every month, I just want a code that take the name of active excel sheet when I run the code.

I tried this code but it was not working in google colab.

```
import os
os.listdir('.')
```

Excel File Name:
[image]

Code Image:
[image]

Code in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sPf-O3KLydPE9eWAINRtd51nHg5naewj?usp=sharing)

Excel File [Attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KOJoHHB0UM4mPMS8TVVDcRSv-fhztQpc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pandas will not help you list the sheets in a workbook. Try the openpyxl library. It is unclear given the code you have provided, where you are trying to list sheet names.

Comment: I just want a active excel sheet name. Instead of 'name of the source file', i want active excel sheet name.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used google colab, but I used to have a similar problem on how to extract sheet names of some Excel file. The solution turned out to be very simple:

```
using pandas as pd

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile("excel_file_name.xlsx")
sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names
```

So, basically the idea is that you want to open the whole Excel file instead of specific sheet of it. This can be done by `pd.ExcelFile( ... )`. Once you have your excel file "open", you can get the names by `some_excel_file.sheet_names`. This is especially useful when you want to loop over all sheets in some excel file. For example, the code can be something like this:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile("excel_file_name.xlsx")
sheet_names = excel_file.sheet_names
for sheet_name in sheet_names:
    # do some operations here for this sheet
```

This is not a complete answer as I am not sure about Google Colab, but I hope this would give you an idea on what you can do to the sheet names.